# How to make webpack to generate the bundling files with the same name on each build?

Tags: react-native, iis, deployment, expo

I'm developing an expo react-native application for cell phones. But now I'm required to publish the web version too. Our deployment server is IIS. Our server-side application is WebAPI 2. So I decided to merge the compiled webapp produced by webpack into the WebAPI 2 server side application. I used the command "npx expo export:web" to generate the production code. I was able to copy the bundled files into the root directory of my WebAPI 2 app and run the full application without major issues.

But when I compiled the expo app again I realized webpack produces a different set of files. I expected it to overwrite the first compilation.

How to do that?

Any hint on how to deploy an expo react-native web app into IIS is welcomed.